# Split json data from json array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting a JsonArray like this, by using **urlrequest** method in jquery

```
Object {
code:"INR"
price:"14999"
status:"sucess"
qty:"5"
title:"Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (Black, 32 GB)"
}
```

Now i need to print, certain jsonarray values, using jquery like this

```
title - Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (Black, 32 GB)
price - 14999
```

Comment: You need to print? Do it, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want print each key and value in your json object use this method. json in the function should be you **json** object. Key and value is your id and value.

```
$.each(json, function(key,value){
            alert("output: "+key+" value "+value); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the properties of the object you can use the keys method that returns the properties of the object and access the object propertywith the dot notation or the [] notation.